# How can I fix conversion error with the same type names?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a problem binding a property of a UserControl in WPF.

The UserControl **UnitEditWpf** is defined in the component **McAnalPrepObjects**. The property **vu** is defined as a DependencyProperty and has the type **ValueWithUnit**, which is also defined in the component **McAnalPrepObjects**.

The control **UnitEditWpf** is used in another UserControl, **NewCurvesViewModel**, defined in a separate DLL.

I have enabled diagnostic messges using *diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High*, and am getting the following messages

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): Found data context element: UnitEditWpf (hash=66136932) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): Activate with root item NewCurvesViewModel (hash=57540904)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491):   At level 0 - for NewCurvesViewModel.DurationUnitValue found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(DurationUnitValue)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): Replace item at level 0 with NewCurvesViewModel (hash=57540904), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(DurationUnitValue)
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'McAnalPrepObjects.ValueWithUnit' and 'McAnalPrepObjects.ValueWithUnit'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=DurationUnitValue; DataItem='NewCurvesViewModel' (HashCode=57540904); target element is 'UnitEditWpf' (Name='uc'); target property is 'vu' (type 'ValueWithUnit')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): GetValue at level 0 from NewCurvesViewModel (hash=57540904) using RuntimePropertyInfo(DurationUnitValue): TimeValue (hash=38717641)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): TransferValue - got raw value TimeValue (hash=38717641)
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='McAnalPrepObjects.TimeValue' BindingExpression:Path=DurationUnitValue; DataItem='NewCurvesViewModel' (HashCode=57540904); target element is 'UnitEditWpf' (Name='uc'); target property is 'vu' (type 'ValueWithUnit')
System.Windows.Data Warning: 87 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): TransferValue - value TimeValue (hash=38717641) is not valid for target
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): TransferValue - using fallback/default value <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=64274491): TransferValue - using final value <null>
```

This line is interesting

> Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'McAnalPrepObjects.ValueWithUnit' and 'McAnalPrepObjects.ValueWithUnit'.

What can possibly cause this error?

Could it result from building components in the wrong order?

**Edit**

The UserControl is used in XAML with

```
<apo:UnitEditWpf vu="{Binding DurationUnitValue}" />
```

DurationValue is a property of the ViewModel class, defined as follows.

```
private TimeValue _durationUnitValue;
public ValueWithUnit DurationUnitValue { get { return _durationUnitValue as ValueWithUnit; } }
```

TimeValue is a class derived from ValueWithUnit.

Comment: Please, if you are going to vote a question down, give some feedback about what is wrong with the question. This is a real question, for which I have not been able to find an answer. I think that I have provided enough detail. If you think I should provide source code, please tell me.

Comment: I' no XAML expert, but the line reads like you have to create an [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.IValueConverter) for your datatype, because XAML cannot use the default one.

Comment: What's the the type of the `DurationUnitValue` source property of `NewCurvesViewModel` and how exactly is `ValueWithUnit` defined? The downvote is probably because you have omitted some important details in your question.

Comment: @zx485 It certainly reads like that, but it specifies the same type name twice. It would require a converter from _McAnalPrepObjects.ValueWithUnit_ to _McAnalPrepObjects.ValueWithUnit_.

Comment: @PhilJollans: It's stull unclear how `ValueWithUnit` is defined.

Comment: @mm8, I have added a lot more detail.

Comment: @PhilJollans: Did you try use a temporarily use a converter to see what value you are getting in the `Convert` method? By the way, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @mm8, thanks again. I had not tried using a converter. I have done now, and I have added more information to the question.

Comment: I agree that it is a good idea to create a simple example, not least because there is a good chance of finding the error in the process.

Comment: @PhilJollans: You shouldn't need to "convert" to the base class. `_durationUnitValue as ValueWithUnit` is pointless if `_durationUnitValue` is a `TimeValue` and `TimeValue` derives from `ValueWithUnit`. Then `durationUnitValue` is always a `ValueWithUnit` (and a `TimeValue` of course).

Comment: @mm8: Of course not, I shouldn't need the converter at all. And it seems like the binding logic still considers it to be a TimeValue, despite my explicit conversion.

Comment: @PhilJollans: I was referring to the implementation of your `DurationUnitValue` property. It *is* still a `TimeValue`. A `TimeValue` is *always* a `TimeValue`. The type of an object in memory doesn't suddenly change.

Comment: @mm8: OK, I have taken that out, but it makes no difference. The conversion is unnecessary, but harmless.

Comment: @PhilJollans: Please provide a mininal reproducable example of your issue.

Comment: @mm8: Thanks for your help. I will try to do that.

Comment: @mm8: I have finally solved this problem and posted an answer. I have now removed a lot of the additional details that I added to the question yesterday, because they don't seem relevant. Thanks again for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally localized the problem.

Firstly, I tried to create a "Minimal, Reproducible Example", but I was not able to. 
In retrospect there is no way that I was going manage this.
Instead I tried making changes in the actual application.

Initially I created a duplicate UserControl in the component McAnalPrepObjects, with a single dependency property of type ValueWithUnit (the base class). 
I added an instance of the UserControl to the same XAML file where the original control was used, in the component McPYR. This had the same problem.

Then I added a second dependency property of type TimeValue (the derived class). Again, this had the same problem.

Then I made a second, identical copy of the the UserControl in the component McPYR, where it is being used. This time it worked!

In the error case, the message  - as in the orginal question is

> Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'McAnalPrepObjects.ValueWithUnit' and 'McAnalPrepObjects.ValueWithUnit'.

This suggests that there are two types with the same name. Is that possible?

Then I examined the list of loaded modules in the Modules window, and was shocked to find that McAnalPrepObjects appeared 4 times!!

[image]

This is partly because I have enabled native mode debugging. This seems to cause managed dlls to appear twice. Two of them appear to be related to native mode debugging, but that still leaves one too many.

The details of this are not so important, and very specific to the application. The application contains a scripting engine and one instance wa being loaded by that scripting engine. In addition I had a symbolic link from the directory in "Program Files (x86)" to the output directory in our build environment. 
The two paths in fact refer to the same file, but the .NET framework would not know that. I can fix these problems.

So the real answer to my question is that the message

> Cannot create default converter to perform 'one-way' conversions between types 'A' and 'A'.

may mean that the component containing type A is loaded twice.